English version of Petersen's 1891 Acta Mathematica paper "Die Theorie der regulären graphs"
Does anyone have a pointer to the English version of Petersen's 1891 Acta Mathematica paper [1], which is in German? Specifically, I need the discussion of the properties of regular graphs and 1-factor a.k.a. perfect matching (and also other properties for that matter)!
Additionally, it is known that this work precedes Berge's 1957 PNAS paper [2] as far as establishing the relation between maximum matching and augmenting paths, a key lemma in Edmonds' Blossom Algorithm, is concerned. I am not sure whether Petersen just "observed" this relation or actually casually "proved" it as a simple consequence of one of their theorems.
I very highly appreciate any pointer whatsoever!!
PS: Meine Kenntnisse der deutschen Sprache beschränken sich auf diese Aussage, die ich mir von Google übersetzen ließ.
[1] - https://projecteuclid.org/journals/acta-mathematica/volume-15/issue-none/Die-Theorie-der-regulären-graphs/10.1007/BF02392606.full
[2] - https://www.pnas.org/doi/pdf/10.1073/pnas.43.9.842

The text is selectable. Did you try to copy paste it to a translator like deepl.com? Also, why do you assume that there is an English version?

Thanks for the pointer. Yes, but I think the paper is too technical for online translators to get the required precision. Also, given the seminal nature of the paper, I assume it may be doing rounds in many languages --  English being one of them I can comprehend.

Maybe you find in this paper something: https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0012365X9290639W

Similar question here

I've had good success translating papers like this using modern translating tools.

An extract of this paper translated in English appears in Graph Theory, 1736–1936 edited by Norman L. Biggs, E. Keith Lloyd, and Robin J. Wilson. (It looks like they translated the first 9 claims.)

Thanks @Smylic. Your pointers helped. Any idea if I can get the remainder of the part? Also, @ all, translations are giving me conflicting statements and hence, given the need for absolute correctness, I am not able to rely on the translated results (for eg, translations interchangeably use even degree of a vertex and even number of vertices, which definitely seems incorrect).
